# Por que no ocurre nada JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy estudiando del libro javascript jon duckett, y en varios ejemplos me topo con que el codigo no funciona correctamente, este es uno de ellos, deberia aparecer algo en pantalla pero no lo hace, tengo algo mal en mi sintaxis, soy nuevo en esto.

```js
var i = 1;
var msg = "";

while(i > 10){
 msg = i + "X 5 = " + (i * 5) + "<br>";
 i++;
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = msg;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    
</head>

<body>
    <p id = "answer"></p>
</body>
<script src="/pruebas/prueba.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¿Conoces el meme que había hace años sobre programación?

- "Mi codigo no funciona, no se que hacer"
- "Cambia > por <"
- "Ahora si, gracias"

Pues es lo que ocurre aquí, el bucle `while` se ejecuta mientras la condición que está dentro devuelva verdadero. Además, si quieres crear un "mensaje" que vaya añadiendo más a medida que itere, tendrás que concatenar "+".

```
var i = 1;
var msg = "";

while(i < 10){
    msg += i + "X 5 = " + (i * 5) + "<br>"; // Concatenas mensajes
    i++;
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = msg;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, claramente fue un error de tipeo, algo estupido de mi parte no notarlo, estoy comenzando en este mundo de la programacion y supongo que esta clase de errores se ven a menudo, gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 4):

La condición debería estar invertida. "Mientras que i sea menor de 10"

```
while(i < 10){
```

Además, puede que quieras todos los resultado, lo que sería:

```
msg += i + "X 5 = " + (i * 5) + "<br>";
```

Para concatenar todos en una misma variable

Answer (score 4):

Tú problema está en el `while`

> while(i < 10)

Esperas que `i` sea mayor (`>`) que 10 en lugar de menor (`<`)

Answer (score 4):

Se puede deber a que en el código js:

```
var i = 1;
var msg = "";

while(i > 10){
    msg = i + "X 5 = " + (i * 5) + "<br>";
    i++;
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = msg;
```

La variable 'i' vale 1, pero el while funcionará mientras i sea mayor que 10 (i > 10), por lo tanto nunca entra en el ciclo.

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer el libro esta bien, esto es como debería estar tu código

```
var i = l; //Set counter to 1
var msg = ''; //Message

//Store 5 ti mes tabl e in a variable
while (i < 10) {
  msg += i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + '<br />';
  i++ ;
}

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = msg;
```

Fuente: Libro de Jon

[image: While]

Comment: Favor de leer [answer]